# Hibernate - Centralized entity instantiation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I have some old code that basically uses singleton services inside entities to perform some tasks, and to start cleaning up thinks, I want to inject those services on entities, so at least I can break that hard dependencies for now.

I'm trying to find some place in Hibernate where I can control entities instantiation, by now I've found some possible hooks, like:
- org.hibernate.tuple.Instantiator
- org.hibernate.Interceptor

I need to control that instantiation when an object is first loaded from database, as well as when it's loaded from cache... Also, maybe a global PreLoadEvent may help, I just need to make sure that when an object is returned from Hibernate, it has all it's (service) dependencies injected (spring is already here).

Can someone please point me to where to continue the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some testing, an instance of `org.hibernate.event.PreLoadEventListener` does the trick.

It gets called always, no matter where the instance came from. This way I'm not controlling instantiation, but at least I have a place to inject dependencies befor the instance is returned to client code.

Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@Configurable` annotation,

see [this blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2008/01/23/new-improvements-in-domain-object-dependnecy-injection-feature/)  for more info.

Comment: That should help for shure, but I'm looking for a more Hibernate way to do it, if such one exists! Thanks!